# Генерация числовой последовательностей T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Где можно прочитать и посмотреть примеры по созданию и использованию генераторов последовательностей в Transact-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Генерация числовых последовательностей](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Всеобъемлющая информация по созданию последовательностей на MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Как получать следующий номер из последовательности тут: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx

А ещё вы уверены, что именно последовательность вам нужна? Может обычный[IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186775.aspx) подойдёт?

Answer (score 1):

В t-sql есть два основных способа.

1)для генерации небольших последовательностей удобно пользоваться рекурсией

```
WITH N100000 AS(
  SELECT 1 N
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N+1 FROM N100000 WHERE N<100000
)
SELECT *
FROM N100000
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Удобно тем, что можно быстро получить любое число строк.
однако есть способ быстрее

2) перемножение.

```
WITH X AS(SELECT*FROM(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))X(X))
,N100000 AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1))N
FROM X, X A, X B, X C, X D --, X E, X F ...
)
SELECT *
FROM N100000
```

Это, пожалуй, самый быстрый способ. Но от количества требуемых строк приходится варировать количеством перемножаемых таблиц и приписывать TOP.
Здесь используется нумерация без сортировки ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) - практически бесплатная операция для сервера.